# Change status depending on the status of the products datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this order table with its product. It looked something like this:

```
OrderID : 001            Order Status : ---------

Products Ordered Qty : 3

Products Ordered: (in datagridview)
Status       ProductName        QtyOrdered       QtyReceived
============================================================
Unreceived      p1                   2                0
Complete        p2                   3                3
Incomplete      p3                   4                4
```

Now its order status is supposed to change depending on the status of the products in the datagridview.

If all products status is "Complete", Order Status = Complete Orders.
If even just 1 of the products have "Incomplete", Order Status = Back Orders.
By default all products are Unreceived and Order Status is Unreceived.

This is my code. But it always makes the Order Status = "Complete Orders".
By the way i put this code on the click DataGridView event if that helps.

```
 private void checkorderstatus()
    {
        bool incomplete = true;
        bool complete = true;

        if(dgvReceivedproducts.Rows.Count == Convert.ToInt32(rrQty.Text))
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dgvReceivedproducts.Rows)
            {
                string state = 
rw.Cells[dgvReceivedproducts.Columns["Status"].Index].Value.ToString();

                if (state.Equals("Unreceived"))
                {
                    incomplete = false;
                    break;
                }
                else if (state.Equals("Incomplete"))
                {
                    incomplete = true;
                }

                if (!state.Equals("Complete"))
                {

                    complete = false;
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (incomplete)
            {
                crud.AddRecord("Update Orders Set Status  = 'Back Order'  
where OrderID  = '" + rrorderid.Text + "'  ");

            }

            if (complete)
            {
                crud.AddRecord("Update Orders Set Status  = 'Complete Order'  
where OrderID  = '" + rrorderid.Text + "'  ");

            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: As per your logic the loop will break at the very first instance when product has status `unrecieived`. So if your order has all the products with that status then the loop will break with the first product and `complete` variable will be true and that's why the if block of `complete` will execute and your order will be displayed as complete. You need go put `if (!state.Equals("Complete"))` block first and break the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the input sir i can't seem to make it work. i just decided to split the method to two parts. i think it will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this, i think it will work without splitting code ...

```
private void checkorderstatus()
{
    bool Unreceived = true;
    bool complete = true;

    if (dgvReceivedproducts.Rows.Count == Convert.ToInt32(rrQty.Text))
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dgvReceivedproducts.Rows)
        {
            string state = rw.Cells[dgvReceivedproducts.Columns["Status"].Index].Value.ToString();

            if (!state.Equals("Complete"))
            {
                complete = false;
                if (!state.Equals("Unreceived"))
                {
                    Unreceived = false ;
                }
                break;
            }

        }


        if (complete)
        {
            crud.AddRecord("Update Orders Set Status  = 'Complete Order'  where OrderID = '" + rrorderid.Text + "'  ");

        }else if (Unreceived)
        {
            crud.AddRecord("Update Orders Set Status  = 'Unreceived'  where OrderID = '" + rrorderid.Text + "'  ");

        }else 
        {
            crud.AddRecord("Update Orders Set Status  = 'Back Order'  where OrderID = '" + rrorderid.Text + "'  ");


        }
    }
}
```